# encoded html reportlab python

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luvso.png)I am creating a pdf with reportlab in python I have the following problem one of the data has to show is type longText because html strings have been saved, as I decode it to show it in my pdf if the data arrives as follows, sometimes html will come tables and would like to keep them. I do the following but it still looks the same

```
 comentatios =  '<p><br></p><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td>dato 1</td><td>dato 2</td></tr><tr><td>dato 3</td><td>dato 4</td></tr></tbody></table><p><br></p>'


from six.moves.html_parser import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser()
data = [][enter image description here][1]                                                
data.append(['Comentarios',h.unescape(comentarios),'',''])

t4 = Table(
        data,

  )
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I could already solve it @AMC